# Swapping contents results in invisible characters

Tags: excel, vba

I swap cell contents with the following line

`Sheets("IMPORT").Range("G" & P42 + 1 & ":G100").Value = Sheets("IMPORT").Range("F" & P42 + 1 & ":F100").Value`

Thing is that it results in invisible characters and I don't have a clue why.
These characters aren't present in column F before the swap.
The characters are not selectable and selecting the cell (going into the cell) makes it disappear. I know that there is a hidden character because when I select the cells "count" goes up in the status bar.

Is there a way to prevent this behavior?

Comment: Can you add some screenshots. Not quite understanding this. A cell is a Range object in the Excel object model. Perhaps try interrogating some of  its properties/methods to see that sheds some more light.  https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/excel.range%28object%29 Or you could link it as a Googledocs spreadsheet if data isn't sensitive.

Comment: What is the `CODE()` return for your invisible character?  Is it consistent in all the cells?

Comment: When I tried to eneter `CODE()` I realized that all cells in both columns were formatted as `text` changing it to `general` solved the problem :)